# How find out through terminal that if any system command uses specific system call internally?

Tags: system-calls

I am new to linux.I want to that how to find out through terminal that if any system command uses specific system call internally? Suppose hard linking is to be performed . So "ln" command uses li nk() system call internally. Likewise rm command uses unlink() system call.

Comment: The question is not clear and needs more details. Do you wan to find out if a specific program/command uses a certain system call? Or do you want to monitor a running system to find out which program(s) use a specific system call?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the system calls used by a program with `strace`. For example

```
strace -f ls
```

There are many options, see `man strace` on your system or [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) for details, including the ability to filter its output to show only selected system calls, input/output, etc.

Note that if you `strace` a setuid/setgid program, for example `/usr/bin/passwd` (setuid root), the target application's privileges will be discarded during the trace.